# rails - how to run in production mode against the development database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, development-environment, production-environment, pg

I'm in the process of updating an app to use asset compilation.

I want to try running the server locally in production mode so I do

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
```

and it tries to start up in production mode:

```
=> Rails 3.1.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

but aborts with

```
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection':  
Please install the pg adapter: `gem install activerecord-pg-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/pg_adapter) (RuntimeError)
```

as I have to use postgres in production for a Heroku deploy.
Locally I use mysql2 and I need to use the data there when running locally.

I thought I could just temporarily remove the `pg` reference in the `Gemfile` production group and use `mysql` instead, i.e.

```
group :production
#  gem "pg" # Used for Production for heroku.
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

and I did a bundle install but I still get the pg adapter error - even though I don't have it in my Gemfile and I've bundled.  There's only 1 Gemfile.lock so I assume I don't need to do `RAILS_ENV=production bundle`, though of course I tried it - it didn't help.

My Gemfile lists mysql2 as a dependency and not pg

How can I get the server running locally in production mode against my mysql database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed the production node in your `database.yml` to use mysql2 adapter?

```
production:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: your_database
    host: 127.0.0.1
    username:
    password:
```

Comment: I hadn't and changing it helped.  Unfortunately I am now getting - `... rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- /home/durrantm/.../linker/app/assets/../config/environment (LoadError)`.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: Compare your files config/environments/development.rb and ..production.rb, looks like something is missing.

Comment: btw it looks like that might be coming from config.ru which has `require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
`.  Note - this is an older (originally rails 2) app.

Comment: will accept this as the answer and post my next issue as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

in Gemfile

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

In config/database.yml

```
production:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: your_database
    host: 127.0.0.1
    username: your_username
    password: your_password
```